# What makes the vote buttons in StackOverflow be on different lines?

Tags: css

The vote buttons just have an img tag, span tag, and another img tag. When I try these out in a fresh page, they come out on the same line.
What CSS element exactly is causing them to be on different lines?

```
<img class="vote-up" width="40" height="25" title="This question is useful and clear (click again to undo)" alt="vote up" src="http://sstatic.net/so/img/vote-arrow-up.png"/>
<span class="vote-count-post" title="View upvote and downvote totals" style="cursor: pointer;"> 0 </span>
<img class="vote-down" width="40" height="25" title="This question is unclear or not useful (click again to undo)" alt="vote down" src="http://sstatic.net/so/img/vote-arrow-down.png"/>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are applying `display:block` to all three items. This is important because `img` and `span` elements are *inline* by default, unlike `p` and `div` tags which are *block* elements by default.

Elements that are `display:block` by default take up the whole space left to right, and keep themselves on their own line as well as pushing other elements to the next line. Even if a width is applied that limits their size, they will still remain on their own line unless you change the `position` to absolute or `float` the element.

Answer (score 2):

`display:block;`

> Block-level elements are those
>   elements of the source document that
>   are formatted visually as blocks
>   (e.g., paragraphs). Several values of
>   the 'display' property make an element
>   block-level: 'block', 'list-item', and
>   'run-in' (part of the time; see run-in
>   boxes), and 'table'.
>
> Block-level elements (except for
>   display 'table' elements, which are
>   described in a later chapter) generate
>   a principal block box that contains
>   either only block boxes or only inline
>   boxes. The principal block box
>   establishes the containing block for
>   descendant boxes and generated content
>   and is also the box involved in any
>   positioning scheme. Principal block
>   boxes participate in a block
>   formatting context.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html